# Center div in td and inner center in this div

Tags: html, css, html-table

Right now i have such structure:

https://plnkr.co/edit/62qnaaK0udONld8l0tAv?p=preview

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="10%">
          <span>text</span>

            <div class="hint">
              <span class="icon"></span>
              <span class="recomendation">Some text with recomendation</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>someData</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

and it looks like:

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/4f3e31511a5740958e5ec401855da5ed.png]

Is it possible to do it so it looks like:

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/0a941f1b2ea14823ac1d8a9f6bf866a8.png]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D all is clear on the screen

Comment: No, it's really not.

Comment: @Paulie_D yellow block *vertically* centered in td, red icon vertically centered in div, recomendation vertically centered in div

Comment: @Paulie_D now is it more clear?

Comment: Should the hint be in the "text" `td` making it wider or not?

Comment: @Paulie_D no! text is separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the yellow box appear as pictured in you last link, change the CSS for .hint as follows:

```
.hint {
background: yellow;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Well, this does center the yellow box vertically. If you are wanting the hint recommendation to appear when the red icon is hovered or clicked, consider using a bootstrap tooltip <http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips> or a bootstrap popover <http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers>. You are linking to bootstrap CSS which facilitates this.

Comment: yellow block vertically centered in td, red icon vertically centered in div, recomendation vertically centered in div